# Handling Http 304 Response In Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, httpresponsecache

I am using [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for communication with server and using [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for caching, when server respond with [304](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) (HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED), i got empty body, but according to documentation of HttpURLConnection and HttpResponseCache, in case 304 HttpUrlConnection will fetch the response for the same URL in the cache. While the request for url is cached and i confirmed it. when url is called first time i get proper response (data) while after cached when i called url, Why i am getting empty body (no data).

Comment: are you instanciating this `HttpResponseCache`? or using defaults?

Comment: I am creating cache on start of application reference is this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html

Comment: can i see the second request you´re doing?

Comment: @kashif181 we also encounter same problem. How did you fix this? Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by downloading volley library from official google code repository this is the link 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master.

Actually the volley source code available at github is customized and cause many issues (github link: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley), never download from that link.